# Is it possible to unpack a generic tuple via pattern matching in Rust?

Tags: generics, rust, argument-unpacking

It is possible to perform the following:

```
fn foo((a, b): (i32, f32)) {
  unimplemented!();
}
```

and it can be executed via:

```
let ab = (1, 2.0);
foo(ab);
```

In effect `ab` is unpacked into `a` and `b` separately.

I'd like to do something similar with generics.

```
pub struct QuadTree<(Kx, Ky), V> {
  ...
}
```

Whether this is useful or not I'm not sure how to get this to compile. Ideally I'd like to be able to call something like this:

```
struct Point(i32, i32);    

...

let quad_tree: QuadTree<Point, String> = QuadTree::new();
```

Would this be possible on Rust nightly without macros?

Comment: You are conflating value level construct with type level one. I'd suggest you to clarify the question otherwise it should be closed.

Comment: @edwardw Sorry I don't understand your comment. What do you mean by value level construct and type level one?

Answer (score 3):

You probably want the following:

```
pub struct QuadTree<GenericPoint, V> {
  ...
}
```

Then, you could require (via a trait) that `GenericPoint` offers an x- and a y-acceessor. Possibly you would also require `GenericPoint` to define type aliases for `Kx` and `Ky`.

Comment: This solves my specific problem (+1), thought I still wonder if there is a way to actually perform pattern matching. Would you know of a way?

Comment: @Saxpy Unfortunately, I don't think it is possible with current Rust.